# Nav Bar no Bootstrap não abre no responsivo 768px

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, collapse

Olá, quando clico no botão (que só aparece na resposividade a partir de 768px) o submenu não abre e gera o erroabaixo.

[image: Imagem do Erro]

```
<!doctype html>
```

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href=node_modules/bootstrap/compiler/bootstrap.css>

<link rel="stylesheet" href=node_modules/>
```

```
<nav class="nav bar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">

    <a class="navbar-brand h1" href="#">Curso</a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSite">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSite">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Início</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
</nav>
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse problema está relacionado à **versão 3.5.0** do jQuery. A [Issue](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/4665) no GitHub foi resolvida e você pode encontrar mais informações na publicação sobre [jQuery 3.5.1 Release](https://blog.jquery.com/2020/05/04/jquery-3-5-1-released-fixing-a-regression/).

Para resolver, reinstale o jQuery na versão `3.5.1` (ou outra mais atual, regredir para a versão `3.4.3` também é uma opção):

```
npm remove jquery
npm install jquery@~3.5.1
```